# PDO ->query returns null

Tags: php, pdo

`$dbh->query` works on `$queryUser = $dbh->query`, but not on `$querySessions = $dbh->query`, `$querySessions` is null,

`echo $querySessions == null;` echos 1

and then

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in
>   /path/to/file.php on line (while(count($querySessions->fetchAll()) !=
>   0))

```
        if($_POST['loginbtn'])
        {
            $User = $_POST['user'];
            $Pass = md5(md5("salt" . $_POST['pass'] . "salt2"));
            if($User)
            {
                if($_POST['pass'])//not $Pass because thats hashed
                {
                    $queryUser = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `UserName` = '" . base64_encode($User) . "' LIMIT 1");
                    $Record = $queryUser->fetch();
                    if($Pass != $Record["Password"])
                    {
                        echo "Incorect password.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if($Record["Banned"] == 1)
                        {
                            echo "Sorry, your banned.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if($Record["NeedsActivation"] == 1)
                            {
                                echo "You must activate your account before you can login.";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $SID = md5(rand(0,0x7fffffff) . "salt3");

                                $querySessions = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `Sessions` WHERE `ID` = " . $SID . " LIMIT 1");
                                echo $querySessions == null;
                                while(count($querySessions->fetchAll()) != 0)
                                {
                                    $SID = md5(rand(0,0x7fffffff) . "salt2");

                                    $querySessions = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `Sessions` WHERE `ID` = " . $SID . " LIMIT 1");
                                }
                                $_SESSION['id'] = $SID;
                                $dbh->query("INSERT INTO  `godzchea_Site`.`Sessions` (`ID` ,`UserID`)VALUES ('" . $SID . "',  '" . $Record["ID"] . "');");
                                echo base64_decode($Record["UserName"]) . " Logged in.";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "You must enter your password.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "You must enter your username.";
            }
        }
```

can any of you see why its being set to null,
and if there's a better way to loop till I get a empty id.

Comment: Could you please do a `var_dump()` of `$querySessions`?

Comment: @jeffpigarelli echo var_dump($querySessions);? "bool(false)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stand in the fact that that query, the one associated to `$querySession` is being a failure. Probably there's an error in your query because what the Manual say is:

```
PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.
```

I'm not sure, but it also could be that no rows has been found.
A suggestion I could give to you, to find out what's the real errors is:

1. You put all of your PDO code inside a try catch block like: `try{/*code in here*/}catch(PDOException $e){ exit($e->getMessage()); }` and see what it output.
2. Take the query and the value of `$SID` and try to run it into phpmyadmin, directly into the database.

*Note that the fatal error is also related to the fact that your query is returning false instead of an object. That errors just say that you are treating `$querySession` as an object but it is not.*

For more information just leave a comment and I'll answer.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks dude, but its working now, I just had to add '' around it

$querySession = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `godzchea_Site`.`Sessions` WHERE `ID` = '" . $SID . "' LIMIT 1");

dunno if my hosting updated something? because it was working a few weeks ago when I wrote the code

Comment: @godzcheater, I guess you are new to Stack Overflow. If this answer helped you in any way you should accept it (select the tick right under the point counter) in order to help other people.

Comment: thanks, you did help although it wasn't necessarily the correct answer

Comment: @godzcheater, you are obliviously free to do anything you want. But if you do not accept an answer other will think this is an unsolved problem. You can also add your own answer to the problem and accept it in 6 days. Anyway, I highly suggest you to always accept answers to your questions if your question has been solved. I repeat. You can create a new answer to your own question yourself, and accept it. Cya.